# Windows 10 restores windows to normal size on lock

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Since the last Windows 10 update (10.0.10586.420) when I *lock* my screen, and I return after a few minutes, many of my windows are restore ***from maximized to normal*** state.

This program was maximized before lock, now when I log in, it looks like this:

[image]

Some windows are confused as they show their maximized sized labels AND normal sized labels as well ( I can't close the window as the button is *not there*)

[image]

Also, my screen lock settings (lock after 5 minutes) are no longer in effect, it randomly locks (if it does) the screen.

What should I do about this behavior?

UPDATE:

Well, it is obviously some *resolution* problem because when I log in, my VirtualBox considers the height of my HD monitor about 1200 pixels. You can see how the main screen has a scrollbar:

[image]

According to [this](http://www.eightforums.com/general-support/61644-resolution-changing-lock-screen.html), it was a known error of Windows 8, but all my settings are default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my **DELL monitor driver** caused the problems. Since their uninstall  my resolution seems to be okay.

*Too bad that my DELL monitor can only be controlled only with those drivers as it has no physical buttons (only the turn off button), so I'm stuck with it now...*